# When I download something from any Browser, exsisting files on my mac appear greyed

Tags: finder, google-chrome, data-transfer

I am relatively new to macOS and have to download many files daily as part of my job.

When I download anything, existing filenames in the finder window are greyed out and it's very hard to read the file names.

Here is how it looks like when I download something

[image: Finder window when I try to download the file]

Here is how normal finder window looks like

[image]

I usually have to replace the old files with new versions. For example, an updated PDF report where an old file is outdated but a new file has a slightly different name so I manually need to click on the old file to replace it with a new file.

I was able to fix it somehow from settings on new Mac but new update few weeks ago runied it. In Settings > Privacy > "Full Disk Access" Chrome and all major browsers I tried are allowed full access - that's what Google suggested.

Answer (score 1):

The 'greyed out' files are entirely normal behaviour for file dialogs.

In an **Open** file dialog, greyed files are those that cannot be selected for opening, e.g. the wrong file type for the application.

In a **Save** file dialog, files are greyed out, because similarly, they are not for 'selecting'; you're adding something else to them.

If you want to overwrite an existing file, you can click on a file, and its name will be placed in the text field for the filename.

There is no way of changing this behaviour (that I know), so I'm surprised when you say you were able to 'fix it'. Perhaps Reducing Transparency or Increasing Contrast in **System Preferences > Accessibility > Display** might help. I can't see how giving a Browser Full Disk Access would help.

There are of course different viewing styles: Icon, List, Column, etc, which might make it easier to identify the files.